# Project Euler 1 in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I have following exercise:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

So I wrote below code which finds the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

**Main.java:**

```
package pl.hubot.projecteuler.problem1;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) sum += i;
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

**How it code works?**

I declared sum variable, iterated through i = 1 to i = 999 and if i is multiply of 3 or 5 then I add it to the sum. Finally, I printed out the sum variable.

**Questions**

- Is it a efficient method to solve this exercise?
- How can I simplify code?
- How can I increase performance of this code?

Comment: Project Euler allows users to submit their code, so you can read the solutions of other people (once you solve the problem).

Comment: Something you might find interesting for such tasks is the IntStream class introduced in Java 8

Comment: Many Project Euler problems have mathematical solutions, rather than algorithmic ones. I don't find them good as programming exercises, to be honest. They are more math exercises to me.

Comment: @JörgWMittag agreed, there are more programming-oriented resources out there; however: PE problems usually are solvable in two ways: You can either use brute force, or you can take a step back and think deeper about the problem and look for smarter ways. If that's not a valuable lesson for programmers as well, I don't know what is

Comment: @styks: You're right. There are other similar sites, where you don't submit the answer, but rather submit the code and they run the code on the server, under a (typically rather strict) time limit, which pretty much *forces* you towards the mathematical solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is very concise, well done!

For this small problem this will be fast enough.

### Code only

I would only add braces around the `if` body:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) { 
            sum += i;
        }
 }
```

For performance, please note that modulo is kind of [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786273/461499). You could implement two variables that hold multiples of 3 and 5.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int threes = 0;
        int fives  = 0;
        int sum    = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (i>threes)
                threes+=3;
            if (i>fives)
                fives+=5;
            if (i == threes || i == fives )
                sum+=i;
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
```

### Math

Better will be to go purely [mathemathical](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Sequences-and-series/Sequences-and-series.faq.question.427328.html):

> The formula for the sum of an arithmetic series is:
>
> **Sn = (n/2) * (a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>n</sub>)**
>
> Sn = the sum of the n terms in the sequence.
>
> a<sub>1</sub> = the first term in the sequence.
>
> a<sub>n</sub> = the nth term in the sequence.

We need to determine the number of items 'n' in the sequence. For simplicity I name this `occurrences`.

This is calculated as dividing the `limit - 1` by `number`. Because the integer division, it is rounded down.

The number a<sub>n</sub> is the last multiple that fits below the limit, which is equal to `occurrences` * `number`

Calculate the sum om the series for threes, fives and fifteens. The solution is:

```
Sum(threes) + Sum(fives) - Sum(fifteens)
```

In code:

```
public static int sum( int limit, int number )
{
    int occurrences = (limit-1) / number;
    //Below is a rewrite ( thnx to Olivier Grégoire) of:
    // (int) ( ( occurrences / 2.0 ) * (  occurrences * number + number) );
    return number * occurrences * (occurrences + 1) / 2;
}
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println(  sum(1000,3) + sum(1000,5) - sum(1000, 15));
}
```

Comment: Why the abuse of parentheses? I would rewrite `int occurrences = (limit - 1) / number; return number * occurrences * (occurrences + 1) / 2;`. No useless doubles (and subsequent cast), less barely readable parentheses. The priority of operations does all the rest.

Comment: The `occurrences` line is surely correct (I edited it), but are you sure about the rounding in the second?

Comment: `occurrences` is either odd or even. `occurrences + 1` is the opposite. When you multiply them both, you always have an even number, which you can safely divide by `2` without any rounding at all.

Comment: Ah and because even * (maybe uneven) number is even too, it will work. Thanks! Will edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

Consider generating multiples of 3 or 5 that way you avoid needing to do `% 3` or `% 5`

Other than that the code is neat and about as simple as you can get really.